# Tkinter widget.cget('variable')

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I obtain a reference to a widget's control variable using `cget('variable')` method?
I am looking for a solution that uses the object returned by `cget('variable')` to find the associated `tkinter.IntVar` object.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar()
print('tkinter variable is of type', type(var)) # <class 'tkinter.IntVar'>

button = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbutton 1', variable=var)
button.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

# Now I attempt to retrieve "var", using cget('variable').
var2 = button.cget('variable')

print('cget("variable") returns an object of type', type(var2)) # <class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>
print(var is var2) # False

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I believe, until you assign `var = var2`, `var is var2` will always return `False`, because theyr at different `id`, you can try by `id(var2)` and `id(var)`

Comment: @Cool Cloud no it is also returning False , but by printing both looking same print(var2,var)      #PY_VAR0  PY_VAR0

Comment: @ArunK I did not mention it as a solution, i was telling the reason as to why it was `False`, what i believed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save yourself loads of headaches and simply store the `IntVar` on the button

```
var        = tk.IntVar()
button     = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbutton 1', variable=var)
button.var = var         # keep a reference on the button itself
```

or like this

```
button     = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Checkbutton 1')
button.var = tk.IntVar()
button.configure(variable=button.var)
```

Unless your real goal is to just get the value without needing a reference, then you can do this:

```
value = button.getvar(str(button.cget("variable")))
print(value)
```

---

As an alternative you can use this tiny class that I made a long time ago. It mostly just automates everything, but it also allows you to associate some arbitrary data with the `Checkbutton`.

```
class Checkbox(tk.Checkbutton):
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self.__var
        
    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        return self.__var.get()
        
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self.__var.set(int(bool(value)))
        
    def __init__(self, master, data=None, on_change=None, on_read=None, **kwargs):
        self.__var = tk.IntVar() if not 'variable' in kwargs else kwargs['variable']
        tk.Checkbutton.__init__(self, master, **{**kwargs, 'variable':self.__var})
        self.data = self['text'] if not data else data
            
        if on_change:
            self.__var.trace('w', lambda *a:on_change(self))
            
        if on_read:
            self.__var.trace('r', lambda *a:on_read(self))
```

Here are some example usages

```
#example 1
def on_change(checkbox):
    print(checkbox.data, checkbox.value)

Checkbox(root, on_change=on_change, text='tester1').grid()
Checkbox(root, on_change=on_change, text='tester2').grid()

#-----------------------------------------------------------
#example 2
cbs = [
    Checkbox(root, text='test1'),
    Checkbox(root, text='test2'),
    Checkbox(root, text='test3'),
    Checkbox(root, text='test4'),
]

for i, cb in enumerate(cbs):
    cb.grid(row=0, column=i)
 
def get_values():
    print(*[f'{cb.data}:{cb.value}' for cb in cbs], sep='\n')
    
tk.Button(root, text="check", command=get_values).grid()

#-----------------------------------------------------------
#example 3
def on_read(checkbox):
    if checkbox.data is True:
        if checkbox.value:
            pass
        else:
            pass
    
cb = Checkbox(root, on_read=on_read, data=(someCondition is True), text='tester1')
cb.grid()
#...
something = cb.value  #triggers on_read
```

Comment: What does `getvar()` do?

Comment: @CoolCloud ~The `str(cget('variable'))` will return something like `PYVAR0` (the name) and putting it in `getvar` will return the value for that name. In this case `0` or `1` depending if the `Checkbutton` is selected.

Comment: All this works fine as a workaround. But, as much as `tkinter` widgets are intertwined with control variables, it is very surprising there is not a dead simple *built-in* way to reference the control variable from the widget.

Comment: I'm trying to use a similar approach here, but to SET a child var value; not GET.

exec( "gui."+str(gui.CM.cget("variable"))+".set(True)" )

This gives me an error because str(gui.CM.cget("variable")) is returning "PY_VAR" instead of the actual var name, which is "cm"

Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: Nevermind! I just discovered the select(), deselect(), and toggle(), methods. I'll leave these comments in case they help others.